# Is there any harm treating binary data as percentage data by grouping it?

Tags: regression, logistic, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation

I am working on a regression problem where I have to estimate the percentage of acceptance of an offer. Although my dependent variable is categorical one. ( I tired to fit the logistic but it didn't turn out very well; despite being 17% of 1s in the whole data set and sample size being more than 100k. My model failed to classify the 1s. Among 4.5k 1s in validation data it classified 20 odds as 1s.

So I took a different way around it and tried to make appear my dependent variable as percentage (rather than  0 or 1) by clubbing 10 rows together. I took the central tendency measure for numerical predictor variables (n = 100 ).

I know that there is a loss of information with this approach. But this manipulated data makes easier to see what my aim of the analysis is.

I am asking this question because I didn't come across anything like this till now? If anyone has worked with similar approach, please give your valuable inputs.

Thanks and Regards,

Artiga

Comment: Have you tried the binomial distribution?  You may need to tweak some parameters of the distribution (and not all software play with the full distribution parameters), but it also sounds like you are trying to manually create a PDF from your data.

Comment: @Tavrock, binomial distribution? like how? I dint get you. Can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: My apologies, I could have sworn I read that you had tried fitting your data to another distribution.  I think it would be helpful to see how your [binomial logistic regression](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-a-logistic-regression-in-r/) actually turned out.

Comment: @Tavrock, I know/read  this already. I have done all possible exploratory analyses. I am not sure what else is remaining to be tried to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2):

Logistic regression does seem like one of the more obvious ways of dealing with a yes/no outcome. When you say that logistic regression failed to classify the 1s, this may point at several things.

Firstly, it may be hard to predict the outcomes from the explanatory variables ("covariates", "independent variables") you have available. You did not say anything about those and how you tried to model them, but I assume that with this large a dataset a lot of options should work well (unless there is a huge number of covariates available). A symptom of that might be that after doing your best you still get no predicted probabilities for being a yes that are much different than the average probability. Sometimes it is just not possible to predict with great certainty. On the other hand it is possible that there is something to be gained in treating covariates differently. E.g. it may be a good idea to allow for non-linearity in continuous covariates, take into account seasonality (e.g. certain things typically happen more at certain times of the year), transforming covariates in a way that is known to make sense (e.g. often GDP per capita may make more sense than GDP) etc.

Secondly, perhaps you are too focused on a yes/no prediction (logistic regression after all provides a p) and/or it is difficult to set a threshold that works well, which may be related to point one. It may be that to set a threshold on the predicted probability that catches most of the 1s, you need to end up predicting that a lot of 0s would be 1s. In fact, if you have in some sense a good model, then when you use $P(Y=1)=0.5$ as a threshold for predicting a 1, you would expect half of the predictions that are made exactly on the threshold to be wrong.

In general, I cannot see a way, in which aggregating data will really help for modeling. As you say, you throw away information and it becomes more difficult to take covariates into account. Using mean covariate information on aggregated percentages for groups is very problematic due to aggregation bias. However, that does not say that it is something one should never do. E.g. it may still be a reasonable way of presenting results or illustrating them, e.g. "Our model predicts that XXX with characteristic YYY are more likely to ZZZ. In fact, when you simply look at those characteristic YYY you immediately see that the proportion is much higher than..." Of course, one problem is that this kind of "naïve" univariate look at the data can easily be misleading or not reflect relationships that are there once you account for other explanatory variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. My current threshold which I am using is 0.5 to classify an outcome as 1 (success). Are you trying to say that I should decrease my threshold values, in this case. But wouldn't my model be a weak one? Also you are right there are around 300 independent variables. I think that can be counted as huge number. I scaled them before I used it in the model.

Comment: Also, what is it mean by aggregation bias?

Comment: 0.5 may not be the optimal threshold (in part the threshold should be determined by the cost of being wrong in either direction). In an ideal work, you'd have a wonderful model that is able to always give you probabilities close to 1 for 1s and close to 0 for 0s (that is of course not just on the training data, where you may be able to achieve that through overfitting). However, that may often not be possible (and perhaps your model is indeed "weak" in that case).

Comment: With that many independent variables, there is likely some danger of overfitting. It may be sensible to use some methods that are designed to deal with that (e.g. the elastic net or some machine learning classification approach such as random forrests).

Comment: Aggregation bias is the bias introduced by looking at the correlation between covariates at a group level. E.g. two sets of people may be on average 50 years old, but one consists of just 50 year olds, while the other one is a half-half-mixture of newborns and 100 year-olds. The two groups have very different expected outcomes in terms of e.g. death within the next year, experiencing typical complications of newborns, developing cancer, probability of job loss, expected personal earning, causing a car accident as the driver, growing in height etc.